# Ruby on Rails Moingoid criteria causes circular dependency error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Installed Mongoid to my project per http://www.mongoid.org

Created a mongoid.yml http://pastebin.com/jS9EptJK

Created a model (scammers.rb) http://pastebin.com/HcQiz3iU

Created a controller (scammers_controller.rb) http://pastebin.com/KCWymF1w

When I call 'scammers#index', I get the following error...

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Scammers
```

On the following line scammers_controller.rb...

```
@reccnt = Scammers.where(email_used: @search_term).count
```

I cannot find where a Circular Dependency could happen, so I'm hoping someone can explain how this error is caused given the code blocks I supplied.

Comment: Scammer should be define in scammer.rb

Comment: Look @ the pastebin for scammers.rb - Scammer class is in there. Are you saying that the file should be renamed to Scammer.rb?

Comment: yes I do, it's the rails convention for autoloading

Comment: Why don't you add this as an answer, so I can flag it as such. Renamed scammers.rb to scammer.rb and changed Scammers.where() to Scammer.where. Works!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails auto loading is very sensitive to convention: `Scammer` should live in `scammer.rb`